# JavaScript событие click реализуется два раза

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

```js
let choices = document.querySelectorAll(".main__filter_btn");

choices.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", createElem);
});

function createElem() {
  let text = this.querySelector(".main__filter_title").innerHTML;
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = "filter__tags-item";
  li.innerHTML = `${text}<span class="filter__tags-item__cross"></span>`;
  tagsList.append(li);
}
```

```html
<div class="main__filter_choice">
  <h3 class="main__filter_name">Режиссёры</h3>
  <div class="main__filter_wrapper">
    <ul class="main__filter_items">
      <li class="main__filter_btn">
        <label class="main__filter_item" for="1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="Боевик">
                                    <span class="main__filter_checkbox"></span>
                                    <p class="main__filter_title">Боевик</p>
                                </label>
      </li>
      <li class="main__filter_btn">
        <label class="main__filter_item" for="2">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="Детектив">
                                    <span class="main__filter_checkbox"></span>
                                    <p class="main__filter_title">Детектив</p>
                                </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Данный код через цикл прописывает событие к каждому элементу класса "main__filter_btn". Чтобы после нажатия на один из этих элементов, создавался html элемент.

Но само событие происходит два раза. Из-за чего это может быть? Я предполагаю, что само событие навешивается два раза, из-за чего?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Это ннеполный код. Видимо "магия" происходит вне приведённого кода. Добавьте более полный html и js

Comment: В приведенном коде нету ошибки.